# How do I wait for a long-running web service call to update its status?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I have a third-party web service that I need to call from the controller in my ASP.NET MVC application. I added a service reference to the provided WSDL and got everything running, but it turns out that the web service takes a very long time to complete (60+ seconds).

I have to create a client and monitor the status of that client in order to determine when the service is complete. According to their sample code, it should look something like this:

```
using (var client = new WebServiceClient())
{
    // Omit all irrelevant client setup...

    client.Process();

    while (client.Status == "Processing")
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

    // The call is finished and the values in the client are now useable...
}
```

This works, but I hate tying up a thread for however long it takes to complete in a production website. Does anyone have any suggestions for a better way to handle this?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect case for async/await.

Comment: Async/await does nothing for this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should offload this to an external process. You can use something like [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) to fire off the task to be completed by something like a console app. Then, you can monitor the status of the job via long-polling or server push via [SignalR](http://signalr.net/). Your main website action just fires and forgets the job and quickly returns a response. The returned webpage, then, would use AJAX or Web Workers (in conjunction with SignalR on the server-side) to check on the status of the job and display progress to the user as updates are available.

See: http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/tracking-progress.html

Comment: OK. We already use Hangfire for other processes. I was just hoping for a simpler solution :) Thanks.